# iTunes Store rejected 114x114 icon

Tags: ios, icons

I'm still trying to get my first App approved in the iTunes Store.  Now they want a 120 x 120 icon.  That's nice, but xCode won't accept a 120 x 120 icon.

What am I missing?

Comment: Xcode won't accept a 120 x 120 icon.? what is this Xcode not decide what apple approve or what not..

Comment: I'm using Xcode 4.6.3.  That's also what is available App Store.  I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As off today, all submitted apps should have an 120x120 app icon. You can just add it to your bundle. No need add it the icon list.

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   delivery for “…”. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to
>   correct the following issues in your next delivery: Invalid Image –
>   For iOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must be
>   in the PNG format. If your application supports the iPhone device
>   family, you must include square icons of the following dimensions:
>   57×57 pixels and 120×120 pixels. If your application supports the iPad
>   device family, you must include square icons of the following
>   dimensions: 72×72 pixels, 76×76 pixels and 152×152 pixels For Mac OS X
>   applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the
>   ICNS format and must include a square 512×512@2x image. If you would
>   like to update your binary for this app, you can reject this binary
>   from the Binary Details page in iTunes Connect. Note that rejecting
>   your binary will remove your app from the review queue and the review
>   process will start over from the beginning when you resubmit your
>   binary.
>
> Regards, The App Store team

Comment: Then which image names are required to be applied for those ipad icon images?

Comment: @Mrunal good question, not sure, just saw this email on a [iPhoneclub](http://www.iphoneclub.nl/280928/apple-stelt-nieuwe-ios-7-iconen-verplicht-voor-ontwikkelaars/) (Dutch)

Comment: what about name specify about 120*120 and 57*57... any idea..? morstly we are add 57*57 as a icon.png and it's @2x with 114 *114 with icon@2x.png but what about 120 *120..?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did need to remove the 114x114 icon to make them happy.

Comment: @Barry: You mean to say we require iPhone icon image with name icon@2x.png and size 120px instead of having 114px?

Comment: That was my experience.  Each new submission was immediately rejected until I removed the 114x114 icon.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) is a Q&A where there is all the files required in your bundle and how they have to be named in your info.plist file.

**EDIT**

http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons mentions that 120x120 icons are for ios 7 app. More informations are available on the apple developer forums.

Comment: this is old one my frnd @zb

Comment: then show me where is written 120*120 image explanation in your shared Doc..?

Comment: answer not pertinent to the question